# Есть ли в Laravel что-то наподобие модулей, как Joomla?

Tags: php, laravel, cms, joomla

Подскажите, только начал изучать Laravel и возник в ходе процесса вопрос. К примеру, у нас есть какой-либо элемент функционала, который может воспроизводиться в другом месте (например, Ajax-поиск по категориям). Как мы это всё организовываем в Laravel, чтобы не писать одно и то же несколько раз? А, например, если у нас AJAX-поиск трансформирует область поиска не на категории, а на посты? Не писать же всё заново, просто это можно укзать в условиях модуля.
P.S. В идеале, можно ли сделать что-то наподобие модуля с возможностью редактирования из админки каких-либо условий, поведения "модуля" в Laravel?

Comment: В Laravel есть тысячи готовых пакетов на все случаи жизни, все они могут быть установлены используя composer. Так же никто вам не запрещает писать собственные пакеты. Так же вы можете реализовать любой функционал для своего приложения. Что касается редактирования модулей из админки, что вы имеете ввиду? Если редактировать код из админки, то идея не очень, а вот редактировать настройки модулей - без проблем. Вообще, в программировании можно вообще все что угодно, если вы готовы это реализовать.

Comment: Вы же понимаете что Laravel это не CMS и что здесь все будет немного (или не совсем) иначе? И собственно админки здесь нет по-умолчанию и ее нужно писать или использовать готовый пакет.

Comment: @Jour получается, мне нужно копать в сторону пакетов. Имел в виду редактировать не код, а настройки, верно. Мне нравится в Joomla система модулей, хотел бы её перенести как-то в Laravel, с учетом этих модулей или пакетов в БД

Comment: @Simon да, верно, то что всё иначе - это я понимаю, ведь Laravel - это фреймворк, а не CMS. Просто я перехожу с CMS и мой мозг проводит параллели с тем, как всё устроено в CMS. Это как изучать иностранные языки, ты судишь по своему нативному некоторые вещи. Админку я вот уже написал, с этим проблем нет, а вот с фронтом и начались вопросы, которые я уместил внутри вопроса

Comment: Нафига, а главное – нафига? Хотите создать что-то такое – используйте компонент. Ещё лучше перестаньте писать фронт на ларе и используйте Vue/React и пилите компоненты там) А бэк уже на ларе, можете хоть модели передавать и получать что хотите (если модели схожи, то поиск работать будет). Короче, как фантазии хватит, так и будет))

Comment: @Alex вполне может быть, что нужный вам функционал уже кто-то реализовал, чтоб не изобретать велосипед, можно использовать готовые пакеты. Правда, никто не гарантирует что все будет именно так, как вы хотите. Что касается фронтенда, то в laravel есть замечательные Liveware/Inertia что позволяет гаразда ускорить разработку.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar подскажите, есть некоторое предубеждение, что у Vue.js есть проблемы с SEO, т.к. роботы обходят без учета JS сайт

Comment: @Alex там есть SSR (Server-Side Rendering) https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia

Comment: @Alex есть еще Nuxt.js (Vue) и Next.js (React), там применяется SSR, потому проблем с SEO нет.

Comment: @Alex Правильно говорят выше, просто юзайте Nuxt для сайтов с SEO, и будет Вам счастье. Скоро ещё и Nuxt 3 в релиз выкатят - будет вообще сказка. Да и поисковые роботы не стоят на месте – гугл уже давненько JS шерстит, у Яндекса в бету тоже вышел рендеринг где-то с месяц назад...